# Do DB permissions flow from primary server to secondary server in SQL log shipping?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, log-shipping

Do DB permissions flow from primary server to secondary server in SQL log shipping?
If someone wants db read permissions on the secondary, do we grant on primary and the permission flows to the secondary or do we just grant the db permissions directly on the secondary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is yes, but only for the user permission on the DB, if you got login and user permission on the server-side, you need to copy these ones to the secondary server to avoid the possible issue in case you do a fail over to the secondary server

Comment: What is the way to copy the logins?